# ls everything that is _not_ a symlink

Tags: bash, ls, symlink

Does `ls` have a way to show negated conditions like "all files which are **not** a symlink"? I use the latter a lot in a project directory but other negations would be useful as well.

For now, my research has only lead to creating an alias to something "like":

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -type l | sort # (...)
```

but obviously this way I don't get the colouring of `ls`, the column formatting, etc...

I am on Bash v3 on OS X 10.8.2 and Bash v4 on Pangolin sometimes.

Comment: See also: [ls content of a directory ignoring symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/141480)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of piping it to `sort`, use ls.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \! -type l -exec ls -d {} +

find . -maxdepth 1 \! -type l | xargs ls -d
```

If you used the zsh shell you could use their non-portable glob extensions:

```
ls -d *(^@)
```

Comment: Thx 4 the answer! Why do you escape !? It seems to be working even without.. What I am risking by not escaping it? Interesting how you use a final `+` and not `\;`, please explain?

Comment: @Robottinosino The `+` makes it send all to a single `ls` command instead of running it separately for each file (this way ls can do the columns and sorting). I escaped the ! because it is a special character to some shells even though yours seems to accept it fine.

Comment: Gotcha. Great stuff! Do you agree that it's a bit laborious though, just to negate a predicate in a simple `ls`? Could there be a better way?

Comment: @Robottinosino Edited with something zsh can do. I don't think bash can do it though.