# How to colourise hidden files in `ls` file listings?

Tags: ls, filenames, colors

`LS_COLORS` environmental variable lets you decide on colours for different file types for GNU coreutil's `ls` command, such as directories, regular files, links etc. I suppose that dot files are considered a variation of the Linux file types and not a type on its own hence there is no option for specifying a display colour for them.

Is there any (other) way you can make `ls` listings show hidden files in a different colour?

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143885/22222) has more than you ever wanted to know about `LS_COLORS`. I couldn't figure out how to get it to work for dotfiles but you might want to check it out.

Comment: @terdon - it doesn't work for dotfiles. It might for some, but very few. There's a limit to an extension's length and most whole filenames will exceed it. It will work for files named `*.hide` for example. [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148369/52934) addresses a similar problem for directories, though the answers to this and the directory problem are probably not the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only sorting by name, this might help:

```
alias ll='LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:"di=0;34:" ; S_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:"fi=0;37:" ; export LS_COLORS; ls -dHhl --color=auto .*; LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:"di=1;94:" ; LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:"fi=1;37:" ; export LS_COLORS$
```

However, it splits the ls command in two parts, one for hidden files and folders, one for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `cf`. I just released a well-documented version, it specifically colors ls output per file extension and/or certain special attributes (executable, links, hidden and directories). Give it a shot!!! It's hard to let go from using this once you get used to it.

https://github.com/AdamDanischewski/cf

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to highlight hidden files (and folders) and you don't care about the coloring of all the other files, then the obvious approach is to run `ls -la | grep -E "^| \.[^/|'.].*"`

If you want to maintain the other colors, then things start to get tricky, because `$LS_COLORS` does not natively support colorizing hidden files as it seems.

I came up with the idea to dynamically append the current directory's hidden files to the `$LS_COLORS` environment variable as a pseudo extension, then execute `ls -la` and after that run `dircolors` to reset the original color schema. Obviously there will be a conflict if a hidden file has the same name as a known extension. Also this method does not work with hidden folders.

**Warning: This solution is a (not very thoroughly tested) hack. Use it at your own risk.**

`for h in $(ls -A | grep "^\."); do LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS*$h=04;05:"; done; ls -la; eval $(dircolors)`