# Make many subdirectories at once

Tags: bash, command-line, wildcards, touch, mkdir

Suppose I have a directory `/`, and it contains many directories `/mydir`, `/hisdir`, `/herdir`, and each of those need to have a similar structure.

For each directory in `/`, there needs to be a directory `doc` and within it a file `doc1.txt`.

One might naively assume they could execute

```
mkdir */doc
touch */doc/doc1.txt
```

but they would be wrong, because wildcards don't work like that.

Is there a way to do this without just making the structure once in an example then `cp`ing it to the others?

And, if not, is there a way to do the above workaround without overwriting any existing files (suppose `mydir` already contains the structure with some data I want to keep)?

EDIT: I'd also like to avoid using a script if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### With `zsh`:

```
dirs=(*(/))
mkdir -- $^dirs/doc
touch -- $^dirs/doc/doc1.txt
```

`(/)` is a *globbing qualifier*, `/` means to select only directories.

`$^array` (reminiscent of `rc`'s `^` operator) is to turn on a brace-like type of expansion on the array, so `$^array/doc` is like `{elt1,elt2,elt3}/doc` (where `elt1`, `elt2`, `elt3` are the elements of the array).

One could also do:

```
mkdir -- *(/e:REPLY+=/doc:)
touch -- */doc(/e:REPLY+=/doc1.txt:)
```

Where `e` is another globbing qualifier that executes some given code on the file to select.

### With `rc`/`es`/`akanga`:

```
dirs = */
mkdir -- $dirs^doc
touch -- $dirs^doc/doc1.txt
```

That's using the `^` operator which is like an enhanced concatenation operator.

`rc` doesn't support *globbing qualifiers* (which is a zsh-only feature). `*/` expands to all the directories *and symlinks to directories*, with `/` appended.

### With `tcsh`:

```
set dirs = */
mkdir -- $dirs:gs:/:/doc::q
touch -- $dirs:gs:/:/doc/doc1.txt::q
```

The `:x` are history modifiers that can also be applied to variable expansions. `:gs` is for global substitute. `:q` *quotes* the words to avoid problems with some characters.

### With `zsh` or `bash`:

```
dirs=(*/)
mkdir -- "${dirs[@]/%/doc}"
touch -- "${dirs[@]/%/doc/doc1.txt}"
```

`${var/pattern/replace}` is the substitute operator in Korn-like shells. With `${array[@]/pattern/replace}`, it's applied to each element of the array. `%` there means *at the end*.

### Various considerations:

`dirs=(*/)` includes directories and symlinks to directories (and there's no way to exclude symlinks other than using `[ -L "$file" ]` in a loop), while `dir=(*(/))` (zsh extension) only includes directories (`dir=(*(-/))` to include symlinks to directories without adding the trailing slash).

They exclude hidden dirs. Each shell has specific option to include hidden files).

If the current directory is writable by others, you potentially have security problems. As one could create a symlink there to cause you to create dirs or files where you would not want to. Even with solutions that don't consider symlinks, there's still a race condition as one may be able to replace a directory with a symlink in between the `dirs=(*/)` and the `mkdir...`.

Answer (score 8):

In bash, use something like these lines:

```
mkdir -p {mydir,hisdir,herdir}/doc
touch {mydir,hisdir,herdir}/doc/doc1.txt
```

The `{...}` syntax is called "brace expansion", and unlike *pathname expansion*, where the filename must exist, the generated results don't need to match anything already there. And the `-p` means create all nested components of the path as needed -- otherwise, you'll get an error as mkdir attempts to create the final "doc" dirs before the parents.

(Check out the examples in the bash man page; creating subdirectories like this is exactly the common use case.)

If mydir, hisdor, and herdir already exist and you don't want to retype them,  Stéphane Chazelas's solution is probably the most clever, but unless you do it all of the time, clever isn't always best — I can never remember the bash array expansion stuff offhand, and I bet many junior sysadmins wouldn't recognize it. In that case, I think I'd recommend either a loop or `find`, like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d \
   -execdir mkdir {}/doc \; -execdir touch {}/doc/doc1.txt \;
```

but, really, the simple loop has the virtue of being straightforward — and not much more typing!

Comment: bash user here. +1 for you. Concise and easy to remember :)

Comment: With `find . -maxdepth 1`, `-execdir` is the same as `-exec`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes. I just think it's a good habit to always use, unless there's a very good reason to use plain `-exec`. It's also the case that the depth options might not be needed at all in the specific scenario needed — could be just `find *` with the `-depth` option. (But they're good to generally be comfortable with!)

Comment: Note however than none of `-maxdepth`, `-mindepth`, `-execdir` or embedding `{}` in an argument is standard/portable. And while `-execdir` generally improves security/reliability, in this very case, it doesn't remove the race condition. Also note that it will not skip hidden dirs.

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in /*/
do  [ -d "$d" ] || break
    f=$d/docs/doc1.txt    
    mkdir -p -- "${f%/*}"
    touch -- "$f"
done
```

I think it meets your goals. Maybe I'm missing something though.

Else you could:

```
set -- /*/
[ -d "$1" ] && 
printf 'd=$%d
    mkdir -p -- "$d/docs" && 
    touch -- "$d/docs/doc1.txt"
' $(seq "$#") | sh -s -- "$@"
```

Or:

```
set -- /*/
while [ -d "$1" ] 
do  mkdir -p -- "$1"/docs
    touch -- "$1"/docs/doc1.txt
shift ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's make it **short**:

`ls -1|xargs -i% bash -c 'mkdir %/doc;>>%/doc/doc1.txt'`

- We are on a directoy like your **start directory**.

- `ls -1`<sup>1</sup> lists `herdir` etc, one per line (there is nothing else)
- `xarg` runs a shell with a script argument, replacing the % by the directory
- For each directory:

  - `bash` runs it's one string argument as a shell script, containing two commands

    - `mkdir %/doc` creating the directory
    - `>>%/doc/doc1.txt` creating the empty file<sup>2</sup>

```
$ ls
$ mkdir mydir hisdir herdir
$ ls                       
herdir  hisdir  mydir
$ ls -1|xargs -i% bash -c 'mkdir %/doc;>>%/doc/doc1.txt'
$ find
.
./herdir
./herdir/doc
./herdir/doc/doc1.txt
./hisdir
./hisdir/doc
./hisdir/doc/doc1.txt
./mydir
./mydir/doc
./mydir/doc/doc1.txt
```

---

<sub>1) Artistic freedom; [find . -maxdepth 1 -type d](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)</sub>

<sub>2) `>>file` creates an empty file here, similar to touch. It's `bash` speciffic, see [man bash, use key / to search for "Redirection of output"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html)</sub>

Comment: Hmm... I do not get what you are trying to say, on the language/psychology level - except, of course, the part about `touch f` and '>f' - that's actually a relly bad error, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: here you say: `ls -1` lists `herdir` etc, one per line *(there is nothing else)* - *but there might be*. Like any files in `/` are also listed, and if any of those directories contain `$IFS` chars the pathname arguments split incorrectly.

Comment: I absolutely assumed to start from the situation described in the question. So I should make that clear. I ignored starting in the filesystem root.

Comment: The dangerous description of ">f" is fixed.

Comment: The use of `>f` is replaced by `>>f` now.

Comment: I was a little nervous about the first line of the example, knowing that the OP has no clear concept of the `/` directory ;) Not really needed anyway...

Comment: I think it is better - but I do not upvote it because it still creates `/some.file/docs/docs.txt`

Comment: I think it is likely a `chroot`.

Comment: I thought about that, but you still need a hardlink to libc.so and your shell, righ? It may be possible to magically inject file descriptors from outside the chroot - but it's hard to run a system without ever opening any files. So I think the example structure makes not much sense, maybe the OP did not really mean `/`?

Comment: ok... but what makes you believe those things are not there?

Comment: He states that there are many subdirs, and there needs to be a doc/doc1.txt in all subdirs. Also, all directories have a similar structure. It makes no sense that `/` is actually the filesystem root un many aspects, but make it a `./`, and all makes sense, for example, it he's in `/home`.

Comment: That's probably true. I dunno, honestly - I just assumed `chroot`. I don't think it matters though because regardless of where it is `ls -1` still gets files and directories and breaks on `$IFS`. That's the only reason I haven't upvoted this anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv As you see, I tried to respect the requirement of "no shellscript", last line of question. And was wondering why nobody else seemed to care? Is it just that it was edited in after all other answers were posted? Makes more sense. And on 'ls' - was just reading the last page of `pinfo ls`, hoping to find a -0 option. Looks like escaping newlines could work.

Comment: [`ls` can do nulls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143885/52934)