# Move multiple files in folders with same structure

Tags: files, zsh, directory

In a project I am working on, I originally had some directory named assets, with a large number of directories, whose names are not predictable, each of these directories contained a number of files, whose names were the same for each directory (but with different content). My original file-structure would look something like this:

```
assets
|
|-some_dir
|  |-blue.txt
|  |-apple.txt
|  |-red.txt
|  |-banana.txt
|
|-some_other_dir
|  |-blue.txt
|  |-apple.txt
|  |-red.txt
|  |-banana.txt
...
|-yet_another_dir
|  |-blue.txt
|  |-apple.txt
|  |-red.txt
|  |-banana.txt
```

Obviously, the files and directories don't have these exact names. I want to introduce a new file structure, such that the files stay in the same directories, but are put within other directories within these directories: ie. I want:

```
assets
|
|-some_dir
|  |-colors
|  |  |-blue.txt
|  |  |-red.txt
|  |-fruits
|  |  |-apple.txt
|  |  |-banana.txt
|
|-some_other_dir
|  |-colors
|  |  |-blue.txt
|  |  |-red.txt
|  |-fruits
|  |  |-apple.txt
|  |  |-banana.txt
...
|-yet_another_dir
|  |-colors
|  |  |-blue.txt
|  |  |-red.txt
|  |-fruits
|  |  |-apple.txt
|  |  |-banana.txt
```

There are so many directories in assets, that going through each by hand is not an option, so I want to do this in one, or at least very few shell-commands (I am on zsh by the way).

I am able to create the subdirectories inside each directory, using the reply to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148382/make-many-subdirectories-at-once) but I can not figure out how to move the files into the new directory, keeping in mind that each file shall only be moved to the directory inside the directory it is in already.

Edit: since this is not clear: I am willing to move each of the files (per name) individually to sort them correctly (there are only a handful of files per directory) but I will not repeat this for each individual directory

Comment: How would your new tool know that banana is a fruit and blue is a colour?

Comment: I would be willing to move each of the files (per name) individually to sort them correctly (there are only a handful) but I will not repeat this for each individual directory

Comment: So you have a "template" directory with all files set / distributed correctly, and you want that repeated for all further directories? How would your new tool know the template directory?

Comment: If you by "template" mean that I know what the final result for each directory shall look like, yes; but what I need is just an automated way of repeating mv file folder (for instance `mv blue.txt colors/`) inside every single directory; and I am assuming that such an automated way already exists, so I did not think that I was asking for a new tool.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
autoload -U zmv
mkdir-and-mv() {
  mkdir -p -- "$2:h" &&
    mv -- "$@"
}

typeset -A c
c=(
  blue   colors
  red    colors
  apple  fruits
  banana fruits
)

zmv -n -P mkdir-and-mv "(**/)((${(j:|:)${(@bk)c}}).txt)" '$1$c[$3]/$2'
```

(remove the `-n` for dry-run if happy)